# getting nearest past date value on sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to find the closing balance of particular date . The table structure is as below

```
    MainCode    TranDate    Balance
    930000003   2013-11-06  564481526.51
    930000003   2013-11-07  571703938.55
    930000003   2013-11-08  571690438.55
    930000003   2013-11-10  551992179.45
```

when i fire

```
select
 Trandate,Balance 
from tbl where MainCode='930000003' and
TranDate ='2013-11-06'
```

then it will return `564481526.51`
but problem is there is no transaction on **2013-11-09** , in that case i have to take balance of `2013-11-08` , if there is no transaction on 2013-11-08 too then i have to take balance of 2013-11-07 and so on.. i.e i have to take balance of nearest (past) date transaction if there is no transaction on given date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order the data by date and take the first record with  `top`

```
select top 1 Trandate,Balance 
from tbl 
where MainCode='930000003' 
and TranDate <= '2013-11-09' 
order by TranDate desc
```

Comment: This'll work perfectly here. For future reference, you can also use DATEDIFF (with ABS) in case of comparisons to either future or past dates.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery for the date which is ordered by `TranDate` descending.

```
select Trandate,Balance 
from tbl t1
where t1.MainCode='930000003' 
and t1.TranDate = (SELECT TOP 1 TranDate FROM tbl t2
                   WHERE t1.MainCode=t2.MainCode
                   AND   t2.TranDate <= '2013-11-09'
                   ORDER BY TranDate DESC)
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7ee41/4/0)</kbd>

Comment: i am confused between your and @juergen's solution.. but i think his solution has quicker execution time

Comment: @ersumit: i don't think that there is a great difference with an index on `MainCode`. However, my approach can be different. His query always returns one record, this can return all records where always the correct corresponding `TranDate` is joined. Just remove the `Maincode` filter.